# "Headers rejected by Twitter" when uploading media to Twitpic with TweetSharp/Hammock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, oauth, tweetsharp, twitpic

I'm trying to upload a picture to Twitpic using TweetSharp and Hammock libraries in a WP7 app. The piece of code which uploads the photo is this:

```cs
// Clients.srv is a TweetSharp TwitterClient
RestRequest req = Clients.srv.PrepareEchoRequest();
RestClient client = new RestClient { Authority = "http://api.twitpic.com/", VersionPath = "2" };

req.AddFile("media", e.OriginalFileName, e.ChosenPhoto);
req.AddField("key", "hidden");
req.AddField("message", Tweet.Text);
req.Path = "upload.xml";
req.Method = Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Post; 

client.BeginRequest(req, (RestCallback) uploadCompleted);
```

*Some explanation to the code: this comes from a call to photoPickerTask, `e` is the event argument which contains the photo name and file (an IO.Stream object). All of this is verified to be working.*

The problem is that the response of Twitpic is always "Could not authenticate you: headers rejected by Twitter". The TwitterClient works, the OAuth tokens are all right. The API Key is correct. I don't know if the error comes from my code, from the TweetSharp `PrepareEchoRequest()` function or from Twitpic. Can anybody give me a clue?

Comment: Although it's for PHP, here's a solution that might help http://shkspr.mobi/blog/?p=2084

Comment: @keyboardP, yes, I found that while searching for solutions. But it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @DerekBeattie, I'm not able, I'm debugging the app on a WP7 device (can't use the emulator, it does not have Pictures Hub).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been having the same (& similar) trouble for too many hours today. I finally got it to work by changing the version path to 1 and entering all tokens into the request (as described in the twitpic doco). I thought I tried this exact combination yesterday, but it is working now, so fingers crossed the api isn't updated in the meantime.

```
    TwitterService service = new TwitterService(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    service.AuthenticateWith(accessToken, accessTokenSecret);

    if (thumbnail != null)  // an image post - go through twitpic
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        thumbnail.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Prepare an OAuth Echo request to TwitPic
        RestRequest request = service.PrepareEchoRequest();
        request.Path = "uploadAndPost.xml";
        request.AddField("key", twitpicApiKey);
        request.AddField("consumer_token", consumerKey);
        request.AddField("consumer_secret", consumerSecret);
        request.AddField("oauth_token", accessToken);
        request.AddField("oauth_secret", accessTokenSecret);
        request.AddField("message", "Failwhale!");
        request.AddFile("media", "failwhale" + Environment.TickCount.ToString(), ms, "image/jpeg");

        // Post photo to TwitPic with Hammock
        RestClient client = new RestClient { Authority = "http://api.twitpic.com/", VersionPath = "1" };
        RestResponse response = client.Request(request);

        return response.Content;
    }
```

Comment: I'll try this later and I'll tell you, but seems it will work, thanks :) Just one question, what does that `Environment.TickCount.ToString()` mean?

Comment: Looking at this (about to start the same code) it doesn't seem very sensible to send all the secret codes to twitpic?